# Select range of dates above and below another date

Tags: r

Consider these small dataframes `a` and `b`:

```
a <-structure(list(date = structure(c(16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 16075, 
                                      16076, 16077, 16078, 16079, 16080, 
                                      16081), class = "Date"), 
                   value = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 20L, 22L, 100L)), 
              .Names = c("date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

b <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 16075, 
                                       16076, 16077, 16078, 16079, 16080, 16081), 
                                     class = "Date"), 
                    value = c(200L, 5L, 202L, 101L, 204L, 205L, 7L, 206L, 1000L, 
                              456L, 555L)), 
               .Names = c("date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
               class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a third dataframe with the columns that match plus the two days above and two days below. For example my two values that match are (after merging a and b dataframes):

```
        date value
1 2014-01-02     5
2 2014-01-07     7
```

LETS DO ONLY ONE RECORD FROM ABOVE AND ONE FROM BELOW THE MATCHING RECORDS INSTEAD:
The final dataset should have 1 records from below and 1 from above the matching records from both a and b:

Something like so:

FROM dataframe "a"

`date value
 1 2014-01-01     3 #one record above the matching record from dataframe "a"
 2 2014-01-02     5 #matching record from "a" and "b"
 3 2014-01-03     6 #one record below the matching record from dataframe "a"
 6 2014-01-06     2 #one record above the matching record from dataframe "a"
 7 2014-01-07     7 #matching record from "a" and "b"
 8 2014-01-08    12 #one record below the matching record from dataframe "a"`

FROM dataframe "b"

`date value
 1 2014-01-01   200  #one record from above
 2 2014-01-02     5  #matching record from dataframe "a" and "b"
 3 2014-01-03   202   #one record from below
 6 2014-01-06   205   #one record from above
 7 2014-01-07     7  #matching record from dataframe "a" and "b"
 8 2014-01-08   206 # one record from below`

FINAL PRODUCT SHOULD BE A COMBINATION OF BOTH a and b and would look like so:

`date value       date value
 1 2014-01-01     3 2014-01-01   200
 2 2014-01-02     5 2014-01-02     5
 3 2014-01-03     6 2014-01-03   202
 6 2014-01-06     2 2014-01-06   205
 7 2014-01-07     7 2014-01-07     7
 8 2014-01-08    12 2014-01-08   206`

Comment: So why do you have two data.frames `a` and `b`? Is your input a third data.frame with those two rows? What exactly will the output look like? Will it have rows form both `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I don't have the rep yet. If you want a new dataframe to contain only the rows in both a and b, one way to do it is:

```
foo <- rbind(a, b)
foo.match <- unique(foo[duplicated(foo), ])
rownames(foo.match) <- 1:nrow(foo.match)

> foo.match
        date value
1 2014-01-02     5
2 2014-01-07     7
```

I do not understand the second part of your question (the two days above and two days below). What exactly do you want the output to look like?

**Edit:**

Here is a quick solution to your problem. **Assumption**: This solutions assumes that a and b always have the same number of rows and same dates, and that "value" is always an integer.

```
# sort the data by date to be safe                                             
a <- a[order(a$date), ]                                                        
b <- b[order(b$date), ]                                                        

# determine which rows in a and b match                                        
match.rows <- which(a$date == b$date & a$value == b$value)                     

# get the rows indices above and below the matching values                     
idx <- c(match.rows, match.rows + 1, match.rows - 1)                           
final.data <- cbind(a[idx, ], b[idx, ])                                        

> final.data                                                                     
        date value       date value                                              
2 2014-01-02     5 2014-01-02     5                                              
7 2014-01-07     7 2014-01-07     7                                              
3 2014-01-03     6 2014-01-03   202                                              
8 2014-01-08    12 2014-01-08   206                                              
1 2014-01-01     3 2014-01-01   200                                              
6 2014-01-06     2 2014-01-06   205
```

This is the simple case. You will have to adjust the code if for example, one of the matching rows is the first day or last day. Cases where a and b have different sizes or different dates etc. are a bit more complicated and will likely require more thought.

Comment: Since I only have two values matching the two dataframes, I want to select two more records from each dataset to end up with the two records that match plus the two aditional 2 records from above and below the matching dates.

Comment: Can you please update your original post to EXPLICITLY show what the output should look like because I'm still not sure if I understand your request. The way I understand it, you want the two matching records currently in foo.match, plus an additional 8 records (2014-01-01 from a and b, 2014-01-03 from a and b, 2014-01-06 from a and b, 2014-01-08 from a and b, is this correct?)

Comment: I just updated it, feel free to contact me if is not clear enough

Comment: Thanks, I would never have guessed that you wanted that output from your description. This is why an explicit example is important!

Comment: Thank you very much for the clever idea. I really appreciate and will adjust it to my needs.